# SwiftUI Preview Canvas crashes with core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

This might be an extremely dumb question, so sorry in advance.

I'm playing with core data and SwiftUI and I'm tryna make a simple app to store notes, but I can't seem to get the previews working. The app runs fine on the simulator but crashes on the preview canvas. I've read a lot of Reddit and StackOverflow questions but none of them is related to my problem.

I'm already passing the `context` variable to my views, and I'm 100% sure it's not caused because of that because the crash reports say `Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model`.I know it says it requires a migration, but I didn't change any data model (it's a completely new project), and the app works completely fine on the simulator so I'm not sure if that's really the cause of the crash.

All I can think of is that SwiftUI's preview canvas may share the same database with other projects and it's conflicting (which kinda makes sense since I've got other projects that also use core data, are also made in SwiftUI, and share the name of some entities).

I had these same problems using Realm and I solved them by removing the Realm database file when using the preview canvas so every run would empty the database, and I didn't have any issue.
Is this a good approach? Should I do this?

I'd show my code but it's really just a `ForEach` that iterates through an entity called `Note`.

Comment: Are you setting up the core data context information in the preview provider?

Comment: If your answer to @MwcsMac is yes then I would first start by testing your theory. Start a blank project and create 1 single entity with a unique name and test, if it works then I would move on to a second project and create an entity with the same name used previously and test. If it fails then that's obviously our issue and then I would just wait 2 weeks for swiftUI 2.0 hopefully. If it does work, well then we can look in a different area for the issue.

Comment: @MwcsMac yes, I'm passing the context information to all of my previews.

Comment: @MuhandJumah It seems to be correct. I created a completely new project, and the preview works perfectly until I name my entity `Note`, which gives me the same error (`missing mapping file`).

Comment: Ok so you have to delete the app from the simulator that you have selected and then the preview should work.  The issue is if you have made changes to the core data structure at any point it will cause this error.

Comment: I would also delete preview canvas simulators.

Comment: @MwcsMac I've already done that with no success. It keeps asking for a mapping file. The funny thing is that even if I do a migration it still gives the error.

Comment: I posted an answer, please let me know if it works or not. I couldn't post all that in a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to delete the preview canvas from here

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/
```

then in command line run the following

`killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

finally restart xCode

Comment: Great! Good luck with the rest.

Comment: @Magnas It's a cache bug with xcode as far as I can tell. The problem is it would cache one data model under certain name and when creating a different model it wouldn't create a new one but instead it will reuse the old one (because they have the same name) because it basically found it. by deleting, we are forcing xCode to regenerate those data models from scratch without reuse.

Comment: This has worked for me when the crash is in iOS apps but it seems like Xcode doesn’t keep simulators for Mac apps in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used a simulator you will also need to delete the model's store at /Users/YOURNAME/Library/Application Support

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had this problem again, but I'm sure this should also do the trick. Anyways, following the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311293/9647800) answer also did the trick